# Angular 2 Convert Function Name to Function Reference

Tags: javascript, function, angular

Am moving some javascript logic into an Angular 2 app.  Part of it involves a homegrown library of "formatter" functions [they do more than just formatting, so pipes are not an option] Currently these are passed by name (string) and the receiving function uses window[fName] to convert them to a function reference.

So there's a formatter function:

```
var tickPositionerYMD = function() { ticks=[]; ... complex logic ... return ticks; }
```

And a build function:

```
build(x, y, formatterName) {
 ... 
 formatter = window[formatterName];
 ... 
}
```

And the build is called with a particular formatter:

```
build(xData, yData, 'tickPositionerYMD');
```

In javascript, window[] is used to create a function reference.

Question is ... what's the best way to do this in an Angular 2 component?  Have seen one approach where a service is created with a reference to window ... this is passed in through DI.

A second approach is to create a factory function which given a name, returns a function.

Given those choices, am inclined to go with the factory function.  Being new to Angular, was wondering if I might be missing a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular services.

Each service is a singleton, so when you inject it to your components all all refferences will be pinting to the same instance.

So when you define formatters int your service, you should expose either method `getFormatter(formatterName)` or Map of Formatters and use it like this:

```
// method:
let formatter = formatterService.getFormatter('myForm');

// Map:
let anotherFormatter = formatterService.formatters['myForm']
```

Just don't forget that you inject services not instantiate.